# setTimeout in jquery's each loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This is what i have. My problem is, `each` loop doesn't wait `setTimeout` to complete its job. I have 2 `console.log('elmDuration = ')...` before `slider.goToNextSlide` executed. Which is wrong. I would use generator functions and yield if this is a server side code, but not.

```
$('li').each(function(index, elm){
        var image = $(elm).find('img')[0];
        var video = $(elm).find('video')[0];
        var media = image || video;

        var elmDuration = $(media).attr('data-duration');
        console.log("elmDuration = ", elmDuration);
        (function(){
            setTimeout(slider.goToNextSlide, elmDuration * 1000);
        })();
});
```

I am stuck with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to advance to the next element when the timeout finished, you have to do that manually:

```
var $lis = $('li');
var index = 0;

function next(index) {
    var elem = $lis[index];
    var image = $(elm).find('img')[0];
    var video = $(elm).find('video')[0];
    var media = image || video;

    // if there is always going to be either an img **or** a video element, 
    // you can directly do
    // var  elmDuration = $(elem).find('img, video').attr('data-duration');
    var elmDuration = $(media).attr('data-duration');
    console.log("elmDuration = ", elmDuration);

    setTimeout(function() {
        slider.goToNextSlide();
        if (index < ($lis.length - 1)) {
            next(++index);
        }
   }, elmDuration * 1000);
}

next(index);
```

Answer (score 3):

`each` loop is not going to wait for `setTimeout`. It will execute for all elements in `$('li')` before `setTimeout`s start firing. The purpose of `setTimeout` is to let the code that calls it proceed without interruption and execute the first parameter when timeout occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You have to take the code out of the setTimeout if you want it to execute inside the loop. SetTimeout is a way to execute code in x milliseconds, but it won't execute until the single javascript thread is available. The loop will keep the thread busy, so all the seTimeouts will have to wait until the end.

Comment: understood. But i need to wait for element-specific seconds before execute the code inside setTimeout. How can i handle this?

Comment: you already are doing it. there is no need to wrap `setTimeout` call in another function.